# Properly define a delegate to call functions from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a .h file

```
@protocol SMMessageDelegate

- (void)newMessageReceived:(NSDictionary *)messageContent;

@end
```

In my AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    __weak NSObject <SMMessageDelegate> *messageDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id  _messageDelegate;
```

In AppDelegate.m I am calling

```
[messageDelegate newMessageReceived:m];
```

at some place.

in my ViewController

```
    #import "SMMessageDelegate.h"

    @interface ChatController : UIViewController <SMMessageDelegate>

    ChatController.m

    -(void) viewDidLoad  
   {
      AppDelegate *delegate =  (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        delegate._messageDelegate = self;
   }

    - (void)newMessageReceived:(NSDictionary *)messageContent
    {

    }
```

However when my code transfers to AppDelegate

```
[messageDelegate newMessageReceived:m];
```

It never calls the above ViewController delegate Function. Where Am i wrong in properly defining a delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    __weak NSObject <SMMessageDelegate> *messageDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id  _messageDelegate;
```

With:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SMMessageDelegate>  _messageDelegate;
```